# Why is infrared imagery of Mars' surface sharper / richer in contrast than that from the visible spectrum?

Tags: astronomy, reflection, infrared-radiation

Looking at the terrain of Mars through [Google Mars](http://www.google.com/mars/), it seems to me that the infrared imagery is much crisper, the images from the visible spectrum seem to be somewhat hazy. I'm wondering if that is just an artifact of how the images are made, or if, maybe, the Martian surface really *is* more blurry in the visible spectrum.

Just to give an example of what kind of effect I could imagine, let's say there's fine dust blowing about that is invisible in infrared, so that in that spectrum, you see more of the jagged, more pronounced features in the rocks below.

Comment: Neither resolution is anywhere near limited by the wavelength of light used, so this is up to the lens, resolution of the senor, distance of the camera, etc.  Why would you NOT expect those to vary significantly from different sources?

Comment: @OlinLathrop - I was wondering whether maybe, the image of martian terrain might really *be* more blurry in the visible spectrum. I'll update my post to be more explicit on that.

Comment: No.  Really, what Olin said.  Remember also that you're looking at different solar incidence angles, like when you take a picture of the full moon versus a crescent, the full moon looks less sharp than the crescent just because of the way the sun is hitting it.  The IR mosaics that Google uses are from THEMIS which took images at late afternoon sun, while the optical (probably either Viking or Mars Orbiter Camera) were usually closer to noon sun.